# Accidentally if I pray one waqt salat 2 times, is it a sin?

Tags: salat

Let's say I forgot/confused about my Asr prayer. So I prayed again.
If it turns out to be 2 times, is it a problem?

Answer (score 2):

No why should it be sinful. Who except Allah knows whether any of both will be accepted. At least one might be regarded as a nafl prayer.